# Is there an easy way to know on which variables a thermodynamic potential depends?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, potential, differentiation

I have no problem identifying the variables if the differential form of a potential is given, for example,
$$
dU = T\,dS - P\,dV + \sum_i \mu_i\, dN_i
$$
$U$ is then (like $dU$)  a function of $$S, V, {N_i} \rightarrow U(S,V,{N_i}),$$ from which I can read off the $dx$ parts.

But what can I do if I am given only the integrated form:
$$
U = ST - PV + \sum_i N_i \mu_i
$$

How can I derive the fact that I should take $S$, $V$ and $\mu$ as variables? Why should one not consider $U$ as a function of all variables as $U=U(S, T, V, P, N_1, ...,  \mu_1, ...)$?

**What information is required, or what must I know beforehand to derive the proper dependencies?** Can I simply pick all extensive properties as variables? Can I pick a single variable from all products of the form $X\cdot   Y$? Or can I consider $U$ to be a function of all variables and  still get the right answer?

Comment: There's a mistake in your first equation.  The first law of thermodynamics should read $dE = dW + dQ$, where $dQ = T \, dS$.  So internal energy is a function of entropy $S$, not temperature $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the postulates of thermodynamics that there exists a continuous concave extensive function **that depends on extensive variables**

$$U(S,V,N,...)$$

such that equilibrium is reached when this function is extremal.

So... the fundamental relation is either $U$ or $S$, and it can  depend only on extensive variables.

Once here, you can Legendre-transform this relation to get other dependencies. For example, for the Helmholtz potential,

$F=U-TS$ is a function of ($T$,$V$,$N$...)

But you do know where this potential comes from and the transformation you have performed.

Comment: Could you expand on the first sentence? How does it follow from the postulates that U or S must be concave and depend on extensive properties ?

Comment: The concavity issue is more advances and it has to do with stability. Don't worry for that because it's not needed for this. What is important here is that such function exists and it depends on extensive variables. Fortunately, there's nothing to explain here, because it is just a postulate, so we don't need more. Well, it has its justification on microscopic physics, but thermodynamics take it as a postulate.

Comment: Is there some physical intuition or qualitative argument why this is a good axiom ? I find it a bit weird to postulate that there is a concave and homogeneous function in extensive variables. I don't need the full derivation from statistical mechanics rather a small motivation/explanation how this is physically grounded. Or is there no "simple" explanation ?

Comment: I don't really know right now.... Mathematically, S is related to de "dis-information" of the system, so it depends on extensive variables $S(U,V,N,...)$, but that's statistical mechanics...